# How do I write mathematical equation in R with constants coming from variables?

Tags: r

In R- statistics, suppose I have

```
a <- 5

b <- 3
```

Now I want to write a mathematical equation using expression function as below

```
exp <- expression(a * e ^ (b * x))
```

But I want the values of a and b in the equation instead of the letters,

i.e. I want it to show **5 e^3x.**

How do I do that?

The reason is that I wouldn't know the values a and b in advance and these are coming from fitting an exponential curve, so I cannot use `expression(5 * e ^ (3 * x)).`

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? Simply evaluate the expression at different values of `x` or do you want to plot the function, or...?

Comment: see `?plotmath` -- but it's not easy to read, the answers here are probably more useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
subst <- function(e, ...) do.call(substitute, list(e[[1]], list(...)))
exp <- expression(a * e^(b * x))
subst(exp, a = 1, b = 5)
## 1 * e^(5 * x)
```

Note that while it might appear that the simpler

```
substitute(expression(a * e^(b * x)), list(a = 1, b = 5))
```

works, you cannot simply replace `expression(a * e^(b * x))` with a variable so it only works if your application allows you to hard code the expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `substitute` command

```
a <- 5
b <- 3
substitute(expression(a * e^(b * x)), list(a=a, b=b))
# expression(5 * e^(3 * x))
```

or just

```
substitute(a * e^(b * x), list(a=a, b=b))
# 5 * e^(3 * x)
```

Answer (score 2):

`bquote` might be useful for you.  Here's an example,

```
> a <- 5; b <- 3
> bquote(.(a) * e^(.(b) * x))
# 5 * e^(3 * x)
> a <- 10; b <- 6
> bquote(.(a) * e^(.(b) * x))
# 10 * e^(6 * x)
```

The terms wrapped in `.()` are evaluated in a specified environment.  The result is an unevaluated expression with the `.()` wrapped variables replaced with their assigned values.